# How to bulk insert recipient numbers in Meta Developers Account?

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

Our project needs to add 100000 phone numbers in Meta Dev's recipient list. The WABA is verified. Is there any API for adding recipient numbers? How to do this? Doing it manually is not an optimal solution.

I tried to add numbers in my test Meta Dev account which is not verified account. It is allowing me to add 5 numbers only. This time we need to add recipients in verified account. Is there any different method to add numbers?

Comment: Refer to the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76316709/8987128), it is the provision on testing number, If you add a real business phone number then it won't require verification to send a message to any user's number.